# Visual Desktop for terminal process

Tags: ubuntu

i am trying to making a visual script (mostly to be user friendly for my partner) to show an icon color if the service is running or started. now i know how to do it for a service but i am trying to do it for an app i suppose? i am tyring to use the expressvpn bash script to test if the status is running but im pretty sure theres something wrong in my code or im just missing something. so far it works for changing the colour but cant seem to detect if the service is running or not.
and i checked expressvpn inst in the services listed. any help is appreciated!

```
#!/bin/sh
if 'expressvpn status | grep -q connected'
then
   expressvpn disconnect
   sed -i "s/onv/offv/g" /home/pi/Desktop/VPN
else
   expressvpn connect United\ States
   sed -i "s/offv/onv/g" /home/pi/Desktop/VPN
fi
```